# Tableau is not connecting to Apache drill

Tags: tableau-api, apache-drill

I am trying to connect tableau-desktop-9.3.2 to apache drill-1.8 which is running in sandbox in my personal laptop. Everytime I try to connect to tableau, it is becoming unresponsive. [Click on this hyperlink for tableau screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPAvZ.jpg).

I followed https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-apache-drill-with-tableau-9-desktop/ to connect apache-drill with tableau.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: enabling user impersonation solved my problem